# vue-chartjs with chartkick vertical bar chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, chartkick, vue-chartjs

I am using vue-chartjs https://vue-chartjs.org/

And vue-chartkick https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartkick

With data from a Covid api that vuex stores the .cases object https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/historical/all?lastdays=365

`<bar-chart :data="this.WorldTimelineData"></bar-chart>`

Will display a bar-chart but it is horizontal instead of vertical, how do I make it vertical?

[Photo of horizontal chart, but should be a vertical chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp3jI.png)

`<line-chart :data="this.WorldTimelineData"></line-chart>`

A line-chart with the same data will display a line-chart correctly with the dates on the bottom and the amount on the side.

[line chart with same data, displays correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgeDV.png)

How would I make the vue-chartkick vue-chartjs bar-chart to be vertical instead of horizontal?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use a column chart.

```
<column-chart :data="this.WorldTimelineData"></column-chart>
```